# Handling touch events

Tags: android, touch, touch-event

Here is an example of "strange" touch events handling.

I created sample project to clearly explain the problem.

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<View
    android:id="@+id/red_square"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#F00" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/test_button_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Test button #1" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent_test_button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/test_button_1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:background="#0F0"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test_button_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test button #2" />
</FrameLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/touch_layer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private View mRedSquare;


private GestureDetector mDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            mRedSquare.setTranslationX(mRedSquare.getTranslationX() - distanceX);
            mRedSquare.setTranslationY(mRedSquare.getTranslationY() - distanceY);
            return true;
        }
    });

    mRedSquare = findViewById(R.id.red_square);

    View touchLayer = findViewById(R.id.touch_layer);
    touchLayer.setOnTouchListener(mTouchLayerListener);

    View button1 = findViewById(R.id.test_button_1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button #1 click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("TOUCH_DEBUG", "bt1: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });

    View button2 = findViewById(R.id.test_button_2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button #2 click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("TOUCH_DEBUG", "bt2: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });

    FrameLayout parentOfButton2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_test_button2);
    parentOfButton2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("TOUCH_DEBUG", "bt2 parent: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private View.OnTouchListener mTouchLayerListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
}
```

The problem is that "test_button_1" is clickable (OnTouchListener and OnClickListener work fine), but "test_button_2" isn't. Even OnTouchListener for "parent_test_button_2" doesn't work.

So I have two questions:
 - how make "test_button_2" clickable;
 - why android process touches in that way (I will be very grateful for great description or link to article).

Edit: based on Rajen Raiyarela comment: OnTouchListener added to "parent_test_button_2" is never called.

Comment: why android process touches in that way ... in which way? Also as you have ontouchlistener for parentOfButton2 (android:id = @+id/parent_test_button2), none of your events are reaching to button2. Try removing that.

Comment: OnTouchListener for "parent_test_button_2" is never called. This is the quite "strange" in my mind.